# React Native inner asynch function not being called (unless I scroll)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-native

I have one function on componentDidMount

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (initialPosition) => this._fetchWeather(initialPosition),
  (error) => alert(error.message),
  {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

Inside this._fetchWeather(initialPosition) I have a Fetch() call which makes another call based on the result of the first function (and also another call that happens when that one is concluded)

The asynchronous inner methods are not called on load, but they do execute if I scroll the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot but this started working on its own. I'm not sure if I did anything to make it happen.